# Does Django transaction management works on update()?

Tags: django, transactions

`save()` generates SQL commands as well as emits signals, while `update()` only generates raw SQL. I feel the transaction management would also work on `update()`. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the transaction management will work for `update` statements as it does for `save`.